# Can we compute the gradient of the variance, given a sample which has gradient information?

Tags: probability, descriptive-statistics

I have a set of inputs $X = x_1, x_2, ..., x_n, \ x_i \in \mathbb{R}^k\  \forall i$ (where $k$ is an integer) with associated responses $F = { f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n },\ f_i \in \mathbb{R} \forall i$ and a matrix of associated gradient information $\frac{dF}{dX} = \frac{df_1}{dx_1}, \frac{df_2}{dx_2}, \dots, \frac{df_n}{dx_n}$, where $\frac{df_i}{dx_i} = \frac{df_1}{dx_{i1}}, \frac{df_1}{dx_{i2}}, \dots, \frac{df_1}{dx_{ik}}$.

I am interested in computing the gradient of statistics of $F$ with respect to $X$.

I think I found a way to find the gradient of the expected value:

$E(F(X)) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)$

$\frac{dE(F(X))}{dX} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{E(F(X+h)) - E(F(X))}{h}$

$= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_{i} + h)}{h} - \frac{ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n  f(x_{ij}) }{h}$

$E(\frac{dF}{dX}) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{df}{dx_i} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_i+h)-f(x_i)}{h}$

Therefore, $\frac{dE(F(X))}{dX} = E(\frac{dF}{dX})$, a simple gradient calculation!

I am interested in getting gradient information from more advanced statistics, such as a percentile value ($\alpha(F, f_c) = \sum_{i=1}^n  I_{f(x_i)>f_c}$ ) or the variance $\sigma=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(E(F(X)) - f(x_i))^2}{n}$. Here, I show my best attempt so far at finding the gradient of the standard deviation. Both the percentile and standard deviation gradients are beyond my current grasp.

$\frac{d\sigma(F(X))}{dX} = \frac{sigma(F(X+h)) - sigma(F(X))}{h}$

$=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(E(F(X+h)) - f(x_i+h))^2}{n} - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(E(F(X)) - f(x_i))^2}{n}}{h}=
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{nh}((E(F(X+h)) - f(x_i+h))^2- (E(F(X)) - f(x_i))^2)$

I want to find $\frac{d\sigma(F(X))}{dX}$ or $\frac{d\alpha(F(X), f_c)}{dX}$, like I found $\frac{dE(F(X))}{dX}$. More broadly, is there a name for this branch of probability? Have others done work in this space? I want to know more ways I can approach this problem.